# Adding DocType ruins the entire stylesheet of my html

Tags: html, css

So when I add a DOCtype to pass code validation on my HTML the images that I inserted and background colors on my divs disappeared however the first 4 divs which is my header still has its background color and positioning intact but the height of the divs are not how I specified them. I know that the external CSS is working because of the background color on the first 4 divs is working. But when I just use a plain HTML without specifying DocType it works just fine.

Please help and thank you.

Note: There are external JavaScript on my HTML I don't know if it affects it.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<body> etc...
```

Comment: update your doc type like this (<!DOCTYPE html) and "<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">" like <html>

Comment: Your page has been coded to rely on browser bugs, i.e. to run in Quirks Mode. This is all that can be said without further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed to add px / % in layout.css

now you can add the **DOCTYPE it works!**

```
#header a:hover
{
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 50;
color: black;
font-family: tunga;

}

#Welcome
{
margin-top: 0;
text-align: center;
font-size: 40;
height: 70;
width: auto;
background-color: red;
font-family: Browallia New;

}

#NavContainer
{
margin-top: 0;
margin-left: 250;
height: 60;
width: 700;
background-color: gray;
}

#NavContainer a
{

margin-top: 20;
font-family: Browallia New;
font-size: 18;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 15px;

}
```

it should be

```
#header a:hover
    {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: black;
    font-family: tunga;

    }

    #Welcome
    {
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 70px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: red;
    font-family: Browallia New;

    }

    #NavContainer
    {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 250px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 700px;
    background-color: gray;
    }

    #NavContainer a
    {

    margin-top: 20px;
    font-family: Browallia New;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;

    }
```

Comment: doesn't change anything but my entire code works perfectly without <!doctype html> but I still want to pass validation code so I can't just ignore it.

Comment: I cannot seem to put entire code even if I do `this then paste code doesnt make sense hold on`

Comment: I just give link http://ejdale.net78.net/ just view page source it seems to be running alright but when I validate it I get a lot of errors hope you can help thank you very much!

Comment: hi there thanks I revalidate it and validation says my code is error free however when u said the problem was just on my layout.css I tried replacing that code you wrote in my #header a:hover to #NavContainer a    It did make a little bit of changes but it is almost still the same and the image is still not appearing. You can recheck my page source again I'm not making changes until you replied. Thank you.

Comment: No thank you very much I did not know adding px matters or % as when I was doing it offline it works just fine thatnk you you're a great help.

Comment: for image you didnt give pixel, i have tried now only it is working.go to consol.log find div id="me" add height: 230px;
width: 230px; it will show